# Wildfly difference 8.2.0 and 8.2.1

Tags: wildfly

I am seeing 2 versions (8.2.0 and 8.2.1) of wildfly which were released . What is the difference between two versions? I couldn't find it over the internet

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to see what is in a Wildfly release is to just search on the [Wildfly Jira](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-4946?jql=project%20%3D%20WFLY%20AND%20fixVersion%20%3D%208.2.1.Final%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC%2C%20updated%20DESC).

To save you a click, here are the Jira's in 8.2.1:

- WFLY-4946: Upgrade Xerces to 2.11.0.SP3
- WFLY-4113: 8.2.0.Final build hangs
- WFLY-4945: [8.x] CVE-2014-7849 WildFly Domain Management: Limited RBAC authorization bypass
- WFLY-4944: [8.x] CVE-2014-7853 JacORB Subsystem: Information disclosure via incorrect sensitivity classification of attribute
- WFLY-4947: Upgrade to Undertow 1.1.8.Final
- WFLY-4951: Rhino scripts can fail due to rhino classes not being exposed